# Replace functions of an expression by their zeroth derivative

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, calculus-and-analysis

A quick question on handling expressions.
Suppose I have an expression like:

```
z1 == y[-1] + 1/2 y[0] + 2 y''[0] + 3 w'''[-2]
```

How can I transform it so that the zeroth derivatives are left unevaluated and I get the following expressions :

```
z1 == Hold[y(0)[-1]] + 1/2 Hold[y(0)[0]] + 2 y''[0] + 3 w'''[-2]
```

The closest I could get to a solution was using the function:

```
Replace[#, y_[x_] -> Hold[Derivative[0][y][x]], \[Infinity]]&
```

But this rather yields

```
z1 == Hold[y(0)[-1]] + 1/2 Hold[y(0)[0]] + 2 Hold[(y'')(0)[0]] + 3 Hold[(w(3))(0)[-2]]
```

So the replacement is applied to more than I want it to be.

Answer (score 4):

Almost, try `y[x_] :>` instead of `y_[x_]->` because you need `y`, not whatever head which pattern you called `y`.

`:>` will scope `x` in case when `x` has a value. p.s. you may be interested in `HoldForm` which renders nicely (it is still there though!)

```
z1 == y[-1] + 1/2 y[0] + 2 y''[0] + 3 w'''[-2] /. 
 y[x_] :> HoldForm[Derivative[0][f][x]]
```

[image]